# How to get to control rendered by Sharepoint dynamically?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list-view, design

In a view (by default AllItems.aspx) of a list

[image]

"Inline Editing" enabling at design time in SPD2010 renders green-cross image-button at run time. Its pressing at run-time adds a new line

[image]

How can I set a (e.g. text) string (value) in textbox of a new line in design/coding time?

Comment: I haven't tested this myself but I assume default values still work here - have you tried that? Or do you need some more logic other than a static value?

Comment: I did not want to blur the question, but really I need it in a child list web part below (truncated on picture) where I want to put a parameter - the SelectedID (it is in URL after clicking in "Select" field)  in parent list web part. So, yes I want there a dynamic value depending on what a user has chosen